# tcp socket server to test html5websocket

Tags: html, websocket, tcpserver, tcpsocket, phpwebsocket

Which is best tcp socket server to testing html5websocket? I developing a html5socket based client that will interact with tcp. So I want first a testing server. I am good in PHP but not in sockets programming. So I used PHPwebsocket downloaded from google code. I tried it using its own client and server for testing but it suddenly disconnects and not work as intended so is there any other socket server to test HTML5 websocket client? Which one is better, I can use a python based, or java based tcp server or if in PHP then that can be more convenient. And please tell me what else I need to test HTML5 websocket. I am newbie in sockets. So my concepts are not so clear.

thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to self host then:

- [pywebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/) - Python
- [jwebsocket](http://jwebsocket.org/) - Java
- [jetty with WebSockets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/WebSockets) - Java

You could connect to the Pusher hosted WebSocket API to see if you can connect. More information on the endpoints and Pusher protocol here:
http://pusher.com/docs/pusher_protocol

You would need to sign up for a free Pusher sandbox account to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to "interact with tcp". Do you have specific protocols in mind? If using JMS, XMPP, or AMQP, the Kaazing WebSocket Gateway provides these industry standard APIs and protocols in the browser out-of-the-box. For example, using JMS, you can build pretty complex messaging applications without a single line of server-side code. Everything can run in the client (typically in JavaScript in the browser).

[Here](http://demo.kaazing.com) are some examples showcasing the power of extending rich business protocols all the way to the browser.

Also, the Kaazing gateway comes with free development license; fully functional server for up to 50 concurrent connections, no functionality or time restrictions.